# Configuring Tomcat's JDBCRealm with Oracle DB?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jdbcrealm

I have an Oracle 12 C Multitenant Database and Tomcat 9. My users, roles and password are in a table in the Oracle database. How can I configure a JDBCRealm for Oracle Database?

Comment: By following the instructions. What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I have not configure now. I want just to know if it is possible to build a Realm with Oracle DB. I have just see  many Tutorial about mysql. There is nothing about Oracle DB

Comment: It's  just the same. You only need to adapt the JDBC-Driver according your DB and provide the Table and the required fields roleNameCol="role_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userNameCol="user_name" userRoleTable="tomcat_role" userTable="tomcat_user". That's all. I did it with SQL Server and its running fine